# How to use Group by on a result set response

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've a question on how to apply Java 8 group by. The group by solution in books and other questions / forums illustrates applying on a object property, like a getter method, but my case is bit different. I've a DB query result set which is a List inside List. The inner list is sometimes a `List<Long>` or `List<String>`, and I'm trying to convert to a Map (using group by).

Since, there is no interface / class property attached, so I'm not sure what lambda expression / method reference to use in the `Collectors.groupingBy()`. I tried Function.identity(), but that doesn't seem to work.

E.g. here's a dummy result set:

```
List<List> resultSet = new ArrayList<>(); // didn't declare List<List<Long>> to keep it generic for both Long, and String.
List<Long> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
tmp.add(1L);
tmp.add(20L);
resultSet.add(tmp);

tmp = new ArrayList<>();
tmp.add(1L);
tmp.add(30L);
resultSet.add(tmp);

tmp = new ArrayList<>();
tmp.add(2L);
tmp.add(10L);
resultSet.add(tmp);
```

Say, the db result set has this value from above: 
`[[1, 20], [1, 30], [2, 10]]` then expected output is: `{1=[20,30], 2=[10]}`

Similarly for `[[1, abc], [1, xyz], [2, pqr]]` considering `List<List<String>>` it should result:  `{1=[abc,xyz], 2=[pqr]}`

I came up with the following intermediate code, which isn't even close:

`List<Object> onlyKeys = resultSet.stream().map(a -> a.get(0)).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Output: `[1,2]`

`Map grouup1 = resultSet.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.get(0)));`

Output: `{1=[[1, 20], [1, 30]], 2=[[2, 10]]}`

I've a solution in the imperative style using for loop, nested if conditions, which I totally wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the groupingBy collector with the first element of the list as the key, and then pass the second element to the `mapping` downstream collector. Finally use the toList collector to accumulate the values into a List. Since you have different types such as Long, String et.al. It's worth writing a generic method for the conversion and use it for all the types. Here's how it looks.

```
private static <T> Map<T, List<T>> keyValListToMap(List<List<T>> source) {
    return source.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.get(0), 
            Collectors.mapping(l -> l.get(1), Collectors.toList())));
}
```

And here's your client code.

```
Map<Long, List<Long>> result = keyValListToMap(resultSet);
```

Comment: thank you, it works when I've declare `resultSet` as `List<List<Long>> resultSet = ...`, otherwise i'm getting `Cannot convert from Map<Object,List<Object>> to Map<Long,List<Long>>`. I tried to use `Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(l.get(0)))` to solve the type cast error, but is there any better way when it's declared as `List<List>> resultSet = ...`

Comment: It looks much better now. Thank you.